# how to position radio button outside of a block with css

Tags: css

I would like to create a question row like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/questionh.png/

At this time, my html source is :

```
<p class="questionrow">
  <span class="question">question label</span>
  <span class="reponses">
    <input type='radio' class="radiocontrol"/><label class="radioanswer">Oui</label>
    <input type='radio' class="radiocontrol"/><label class="radioanswer">Non</label>
  </span>
</p>
```

(but i can change it)

ths css is :

```
.questionrow
{
  width:1000px;
  background-color: #EDF2BE;    
}

.question
{
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reponses
{
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.radiocontrol {
  border: 1px solid #006;
  background: #ffc;
}
```

I'd like to have 2 effects :

1. I would like to put the label outside, on top of the colored line. I would like to have the label on the same column of the radio button.
2. I would like to draw a vertical line (but I imagine it will be easy if there is a solution for the previous)

Does someone has some idea about that ?

Regards

Comment: could you put your example up on jsfiddle.net? gets a lot easier !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that closely resembles your sample image...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zjnw9/1/

HTML...

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="q">This is a question?</p>
    <ul class="options">
        <li><label>One</label><input type="radio" /></li>
        <li><label>Two</label><input type="radio" /></li>
        <li><label>Three</label><input type="radio" /></li>
        <li><label>Four</label><input type="radio" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
.row {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
.q {
    background-color: #EDF2BE;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.5em;   
}
.options {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -3.4em;
}
.options li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 0em 0.5em 0.7em;
}
.options label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 9pt;
    padding-bottom: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tables instead? `span` is pretty meaningless for this. This is exactly what tables are meant for.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><label for="radio1">Label 1</label></th>
        <th><label for="radio2">Label 2</label></th>
        <th><label for="radio3">Label 3</label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="group" id="radio1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="group" id="radio2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="group" id="radio3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I thought we had to avoid the use of table now ? Isn't a pure css way ?

Comment: You should avoid tables for layouts. Not for representing data, that's what they are for. Use for everything the most logical HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS solution, without a `table`.

```
div {float:left;padding:0 1em; border-right:1px solid gray; height:50px;}

<div>
    <p>question label</p>
</div>

<div>
    <label>Oui</label><br />
    <input type='radio'/>
</div>

<div>
    <label>Non</label><br />
    <input type='radio'/>
</div>
```

Works in FF and Chrome for me.